# IIF Syntax Error

Tags: c#, vb.net

"The name 'IIF' does not exists in the current context". This is the error I get on using the IFF syntax. Below is my code:

```
string status = IIF(Convert.ToInt32(inputBalance.Text) > 0, "UNSETTLED", "SETTLED");
```

Can you point to me what is wrong with what I have done? Thanks!

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code. The error message suggests that you spelled it `IFF` rather than `IIF`. Which did you actually write?

Comment: There's no iif in C#. The equivalent is ?: so you write your code as string status = Convert.ToInt32(inputBalance.Text)>0?"Unsettled":"Settled";

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that in C# , here's the syntax

```
    string status = Convert.ToInt32(inputBalance.Text) > 0 ? "UNSETTLED" : "SETTLED";
```

VB.NET Syntax:

```
    IIf(someBool, "true", "false")
```

C# Syntax:

```
    someBool ? "true" : "false";
```